# Optimization SQL update on a large table

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I will need your help with a SQL update on a large table (approximately 5 billion rows -base oracle 11g). 
I generate and execute my updates from a SHELL script using SQL plus but the execution of my queries takes a lot of time, is there a way to speed up my updates:

````
Update My_table
Set CODE = ‘F’ where  date=’2020/06/05’ and ID=’87444’  and GROUP=’GGG’ and NUM_FAC=’15444’
Update My_table
Set CODE = ‘D’ where  date=’2020/06/01’ and ID=’85544’  and GROUP=’GGG’ and NUM_FAC=’55555’
Update My_table
Set CODE = ‘I’  where  date=’2020/06/03’ and ID=’85544’  and GROUP=’GGG’ and NUM_FAC=’55555’
….. Plusieurs lignes  
Commit ;  ```
Exit SUCCESS
Thank you in advance for your help.
````

Comment: Until you get an answer, this is a good read: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:::::P11_QUESTION_ID:6407993912330

Comment: Approximately how many of the 5 billion rows will you be updating altogether?  What indexes do you have on the table?

Comment: Are you using Postgresql or Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

Move the common conditions to `WHERE` clause and then use a `CASE` expression:

```
Update My_table
    Set CODE = (CASE WHEN date = '2020/06/05' THEN 'F'
                     WHEN date = '2020/06/01' THEN 'D'
                     WHEN date = '2020/06/03' THEN 'C'
                     . . .
                END)
WHERE ID = '85544'  and GROUP = 'GGG' and NUM_FAC = '55555' AND
      DATE IN ('2020/06/05', '2020/06/01', '2020/06/03', . . . );
```

Comment: Thank you for this return, I tried your request but unfortunately it only works with little data, it falls into error in SQL plus (Error 45 initializing SQL*Plus Internal error ) when I have several lines to update: UPDATE My_table
SET  OPERATION = ( 
CASE 
when  NUM_FA='222' AND NUM_LO='27' THEN '0'
when NUM_FA='333' AND NUM_LO='82' THEN '2'
when NUM_FA='555' AND NUM_LO='82' THEN '8'
…. 7000 lines
END)
where  NUM_EM='FFFF' AND  NUM_DES='GGG'
AND NUM_FA  IN ('222','333', '555'….., 7000 NUM_FA   ) ;
/
EXIT SUCCESS